# Using Vuetify's v-treeview load-children method isn't working with nuxt-content

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js, nuxt-content

I have a Vuetify treeview setup in a NuxtJS app like so:

```html
<v-treeview
  open-all
  color="white"
  class="info-pool"
  :load-children="loadChildren"
  :search="search"
  :filter="filter"
  :items="items">
  <template slot="label" slot-scope="{ item }">
    <a @click="CHANGE_INFO_TOPIC(item)"
       style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;">{{ item.name }}</a>
  </template>
</v-treeview>
```

Whenever a node is opened, it's meant to load its children from NuxtJS's content folder like so:

```js
async loadChildren(item) {
  let topicChildren = await this.$content(`${item.location}/${item.item_key}`).sortBy('id', 'asc').fetch()

  topicChildren.forEach((child) => {
    let subChildren = child.children ? [] : null;
    item.children.push({
      id: child.id,
      name: child.name,
      location: child.location,
      item_key: child.item_key,
      children: subChildren
    })
  })
}
```

This method works as intended, and I can see the desired results in the console log after the load-children method kicks off. The parent node's children key is populated with objects as intended. However, the node in the treeview itself remains empty as if its children was still an empty array.

What could be the reason for this?

- I tried manually pasting the content objects into the node's children array, and they showed up in the treeview. So I know it isn't the formatting of the objects coming from the content fetch method. It must be that the treeview isn't updating after the push.
- The [official docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview/#load-children) show them using a .json() method on the response, but my response is coming from content in array form so I don't believe I need to do that.
- While fetching from content is different than fetching from an API, I'm still populating the children array in the same manner.

Very confused as to why this method would successfully change the item's children array, but the treeview won't update to reflect it.

**Update**

This test method with a return is also not functioning

```js
async loadChildren(item) {
  return await this.$content(`${item.location}/${item.item_key}`).sortBy('id', 'asc').fetch()
    .then(res => {item.children.push(...res)})
}
```

This hardcoded method is also not working. I've tried it with both pushing an array with one object, as well as just an object.

```js
async loadChildren(item) {
  return item.children.push({
    id: 1,
    name: 'blah'
  });
},
```

The documentation states:

> You can dynamically load child data by supplying a Promise callback to
> the load-children prop.This callback will be executed the first time a
> user tries to expand an item that has a children property that is an
> empty array.

So perhaps the issue is that the method needs to return a Promise callback that would push the child objects into the array.

But nuxt-content's fetch() method DOES return a Promise. And I can inspect the node in the component's computed data and see that it has been populated with children. But the node on the treeview still remains empty.

Comment: Even if it's not the case here, you should be aware of some caveats when [using arrays](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays) with Vue2. Also, why don't you use `this.items = topicChildren.map ...` here? Finally, did you checked what is actually in your Vue devtools? To see if it's a display or state issue.

Comment: @kissu I'm following the example for "load children" in [the official docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/treeview/#load-children) which just pushes the children into the array like ```item.children.push(...json)```. I'll try your suggestion but I've been fiddling with different methods of doing this and it all leads to the same result.

Comment: In the example, the prop `:load-children="fetchUsers"` receives a function with a `return` hence a whole array of users. In your case, `topicChildren` is still kept local to your `loadChildren` method (and returns nothing).

Comment: A `return topicChildren.map ...` should be enough. If you're not sure, try to pass a hardcoded array to the `:load-children` prop.

Comment: in the loadChildren you are not returning anything

Comment: What do you have at the end of your edited function here? Are you sure this is an array?

Comment: Hardcoded -> `return [{ id: 1, name: ...}, { id: 2, ...}]`. Here, you're not returning an array, please check the [documentation of `.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) again please. Also, please try to return an array, with a method like [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Because `.push` is actually returning an Integer and not an array...

Comment: Also, if you're using the `async`/`await` syntax (it's nice that way), use it all the way down and don't `.then` in the middle, for consistency.

Comment: Returning an array or an object is having the same result. I can try with a .map() but if you look at Vuetify's documentation they're returning a push

Comment: From the docs: ```You can dynamically load child data by supplying a Promise callback to the load-children prop. This callback will be executed the first time a user tries to expand an item that has a children property that is an empty array.``` Perhaps the problem is the Promise

Comment: Hm indeed, for the point above. Meanwhile, I'm wondering what is actually in `item` when calling `async fetchUsers (item) {` here, looks cryptic. Does it contain `this`? You'll need to inspect the way the component is working at the `:load-children="fetchUsers"` by inspecting any emitted values (via the Vue devtools).

Comment: ```item``` is the object for the viewtree node, including its empty children array. If you look at the latest edit I'm now getting a spinner by returning a Promise. It spins forever but it feels like this is moving closer to a solution. The docs only have examples where they call out to an API not nuxt-content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and found out that putting the tree root into the data also solves the problem.

Before I created the tree root and the first layer myself and not during load-children.

It seems that load-children has to be used for all child layers?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this for a long time I figure out the cause. The node object had an empty array for children like so:

```
computed: {
        items () {
            return [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Info Pool',
                    location: '',
                    item_key: 'info_pool',
                    children: []
                },
            ]
        },
    },
```

When actually the 'empty array' needs to be a separate variable in data() like this:

```
    data () {
        return {
            children: []
        }
    },
    
    computed: {
        items () {
            return [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Info Pool',
                    location: '',
                    item_key: 'info_pool',
                    children: this.children
                },
            ]
        },
    },
```

Just setting the node's children to an empty array will update that array when the Promise returns, but the treeview won't be able to detect the change for some reason.